# ! Package pdftex.def Error: 'eps-converted-to.pdf' not found

Tags: graphics, pdftex, eps

I have following code simply testing I can insert an image. I got the error message basically says:

> ! Package `pdftex.def` Error: `'eps-converted-to.pdf'` not
>   found

I googled a little bit

1. I have an image beer-lambert.eps in the folder of `C:/Users/tsui/writing/chapter_1/figures/`
2. There does not seem to be any space in the path

I don't understand, because I have another LaTeX project, that simply does not have such a problem. So I assume my setup on my MikTex (Windows 10) is correct?

Following is my code.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.4]{C:/Users/tsui/writing/chapter_1/figures/beer-lambert}
\caption{caption}
\label{fig_beer_lambert}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

**Update:**

I change the code, as Ruben suggested, to simplify the problem. Now the `.eps` image is in the same folder as the `.tex` file, but it still gives the same

> 'eps-converted-to.pdf' not found

error:

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}


\begin{document}

\includegraphics[scale=0.4]{sinogram.eps}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Try `\includegraphics[scale=0.4]{beer-lambert.eps}` with `beer-lampert.eps` beeing in the same folder as you `.tex` file

Comment: @Ruben: It gives the same error....

Comment: I can't reproduce your error, it works fine for me with `\includegraphics[scale=0.4]{sinogram.eps}` and also `\includegraphics[scale=0.4]{sinogram}`. Does it work with `\includegraphics[scale=0.4]{example-image}`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really don't know why it did not work, so I decided to uninstall my MikTex. Then I re-downloaded and reinstalled the MikTex, and now it works.

I guess I did not find the root cause, but it was a walk-around. Thanks.

Comment: Good. For future reference: I suggest that you use the portable version of MikTeX. Once you get it working, make a zip archive of everything. Then, in the event of a future problem, you can discard the current installation and revert to the zip archive.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you didn't have a program that converts eps to pdf installed in your system? In the case of Mitex it is *miktex-epstopdf*. I had similar situation, and in the case of Ubuntu and Texlive the solution was to install *repstopdf* from t*exlive-font-utils*.

Comment: Thank you! Installing texlive-font-utils helped indeed.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. In my case the problem was resolved simply by incorporating the \graphicspath{*path of the directory where the image files are kept*} command in the header.

Answer (score 0):

I was using this command

\includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{1.1.pdf}

so this error occurred.

When I replaced this command with this

\includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{Figures/1.1.pdf}

this error removed.
So its path issue at all, my figures are placed in the Figures folder

Comment: Adding path to image is already covered by other answers. Use file names with dot is bad idea and usually lead to errors. Nowadays version of LaTeX don't need to write extension of image type. Graphics driver determine accordingly. So you can write ˙\includegraphics[<optins]{<path_if_needed>/<image-file-name>}` (observe, that file extension is omitted).

Answer (score 0):

When I was using the mdpi template, I encountered a similar error. After reviewing the documentation for the `epstopdf` package, I found that I could compile successfully by adding the following command-line parameters during compilation:

```bash
pdflatex --shell-escape test.tex (TEX Live)
```

or

```bash
pdflatex --enable-write18 test.tex (MiKTEX)
```

Please refer to [this](https://mirror-hk.koddos.net/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/epstopdf-pkg/epstopdf.pdf).

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem, the issue was caused due to mentioning full path of the pdf file. changed to the filename only. Compiles perfectly.

```
\includegraphics[scale=0.4]{C:/Users/tsui/writing/chapter_1/figures/x.pdf}
```

to

```
\includegraphics[scale=0.4]{x.pdf}
```